# knockout how to get $parent of $parent

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

```
<div id="root" data-bind="with: $data.Building">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data.Offices">
        <div data-bind="foreach: $data.desks">
            <div data-bind="foreach: $data.Legs">
                <button class="btnDestroyDeskLeg"> Destroy</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
        $("#root").on('click', '.btnDestroyDeskLeg', function ()
        {
            var context = ko.contextFor(this),
                Office = ** ? **,
                Desk = context.$parent,
                Leg = context.$data;
        });
</script>
```

How can I get $Parent of $Parent?
In other word, what should replace "** ? **" to get office?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `$parents` array as described in [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).

To get a parent context you can use

```
$parents[0]
```

To get grandparent context you can use

```
$parents[1]
```

So in your case you can use

```
Office = context.$parents[1]
```